# ZF2 DI configuration shared

Tags: dependency-injection, zend-framework2, shared

is it possible to disable the shared option for DI?
Found some Patch which suggests that it should work like this:

```
return(array(
'di' => array(
    'definition' => array(
        'class' => array(
            'SomeService' => array(
            ),
        )
    ),
    'instance' => array(
        'SomeService' => array(
            'shared' => false
        ),
    )
)));
```

But unfortunately I always get the same instance when using `$serviceManager->get('SomeService');`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a ZF2 (2.1.5) issue, because the ServiceLocator does not check the DI configuration. A quick and dirty fix is to use `$this->getServiceLocator()->setShared('SomeService', false);` before calling `$serviceManager->get('SomeService');`.

Answer (score 0):

The Service Locator pattern, by definition, will return the same service instance every time.

ZF2 DI is a Service Locator pattern; however, one way to get separate instances is to use aliases:

```
'instance' => array(
    'alias' => array(
        'queue1' => 'Zend_Queue',
        'queue2' => 'Zend_Queue',
    ),
)
```

This example is taken from a ZF2 pre-beta4 project, but should work fine for current ZF2 DI. There may be a better way, currently, to do what you're after (I haven't used DI for a while), but this works well.

---

**Edit**

Looking further into the code, [according to this line](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Di/Config.php#L187), what you did should work. Either the `'shared'` or `'share'` keywords, when placed on the same depth as the `'parameter'` keyword (like you did) should cause `->setShared()` to be called for that service, with the given value passed in.

Unfortunately, I can't be much more help with DI, since I no longer use it.

Comment: It's definately a bug.
I filed a report here: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/4377